# Return records where date is in future range

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query :-

```
select actual_ssd
from tblsales
```

Is it possible to return records from `tblsales` where `actual_ssd` is dynamically 2 months ahead?

So, if I ran the query today, it would return all records between 01/05/2018 and 31/05/2018. And if I ran it on 04/04/2018, it would return all records between 01/06/2018 and 30/06/2018.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure thing

```
 select * 
 from tblsales
 where actual_ssd >= trunc(add_months(sysdate, 2), 'MM')
 and actual_ssd < trunc(add_months(sysdate, 3), 'MM')
```

`trunc()` on a date value performs a rounding down, depending on the format mask; with the `'MM'` argument it rounds down to the first of the current month. `add_months()` does exactly what you'd think it does, add the required number of months to the date argument.

Answer (score 1):

Use `trunc` with arithmetic.

```
where actual_ssd >= trunc(sysdate,'mm')+interval '2' month 
and actual_ssd < trunc(sysdate,'mm')+interval '3' month
```